# Find every positive integer $n$ such that the sums of the distinct prime divisors of $2^n+1$ and $n$ coincide

Tags: number-theory

> For each positive integer $k$, let $C(k)$ denote the sum of the distinct prime divisors of $n$. For example, $C(1)=0$, $C(2)=2$, $C(45)=8$. Find all positive integers $n$ for which $C(2^n+1)=C(n)$.

I have found when $n=3$, the condition holds. How to find the other solutions?

Comment: Hint: show that if $n$ is odd and $p\mid n$ then $(2^p+1) \mid (2^n+1)$.

Comment: "This question has an open bounty worth +50 reputation from communnites ending in 7 days" Good to know, but what did you do with @GregMartin's hint?

Comment: it's always the jargon... that confuses me, gee!

Comment: Zsigmondy kills the problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem

Comment: Do you need to correct the statement: "$C(k)$ denote the sum of the distinct prime divisors of $n$". How do $k$ and $n$ relate?

Comment: @user141614, Zsigmondy deals with the prime factors of $a^n-b^n$ where $a>b>0$, which does not coincide with $2^n+1$ which OP asks.

Comment: If $d$ is an odd divisor of $n$ then $2^n+1=(2^{n/d})^d-(-1)^d$